# What does it mean to "Evaluate the potential of leading order?"

Tags: physics

Given the potential $V(r)$ of some particle $m$ that is affected by it, how does one use Newton's Second Law to *evaluate the potential of leading order*?

I got the DE:

$$mr''r^3=2b-ar,$$ where $a$,$b$ are constant and $'$ is time differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

You have skimped on context here. Multiplying by $r'$ and integrating yields the conserved energy equation,
$$
mr' ^2 /2= a/r -b/r^2 -c , 
$$
suggesting your potential is 
$$
V= c-a/r+ b/r^2 ~.
$$
One normally ignores constants (zero point energy), so the leading term at large distances is *-a/r*, a Coulomb-like term. Is this what you have in mind?